# AJAX and Javascript to display the same for everyone?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, websocket, flask

I have a web app with several AJAX call and from them it draws realtime graphs from the call. And the problem is that everytime we connect to the page, it start over and draw and make calls from there. I want everybody to share the same state of the page, not each person reloading and getting different values.

How do I limit the calls and share the same state for everyone?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague as to exactly what you're trying to do so it's hard for us to do anything more than offer general techniques.  On StackOverflow, you are much more likely to get a helpful answer if you are much more specific about exactly what you're trying to do and how you envision the general approach being structured.  If you care to edit your question to add much more detail, you will probably get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the current state on your server and when a page is requested, you have to build a page from your server that will show the current state.

When anything changes the current state (I don't know what actions can change the state as you haven't stated how that works), then you must update the state on the server so it stays current.

If you want other open clients to update anytime anyone changes the state, then each open page will have to either maintain some sort of open connection to the server like a websocket (so it can be notified of updates to the state and it can update it's visuals) or you will have to poll the server from each open page to find out if anything has been updated.